# Pandas how to perform outer merge with specific order of adding rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames:

```
   df:
      col1  col2
    0   x   1
    1   a   2
    2   b   3
    3   c   4
```

and

```
df2:
      col1  col2
    0   x   1
    1   a   2
    2   f   6
    3   c   4
```

And I want to obtain data frame in which new row from df2 will be added to new data frame after row with the same index from the df, like this:

```
  col1  col2
0   x   1
1   a   2
2   b   3
3   f   6
4   c   4
```

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, how='outer')` or `df2.merge(df1, how='outer')`

Comment: I assume https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882 asnwers your question. If it doesn't, please let me know :)

Comment: It adds new row from df2 at the end of new df, but I need to add this value straight after row with index 2

Comment: Ok, I see you're question isn't a dupe. I reopened it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['x', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['x', 'a', 'f', 'c'],
    'col2': [1, 2, 6, 4]
})
```

In order to get your output, I concatenated the two dataframes and sorted by the index, as requested, then you can set the index in order with `reset_index()`.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates().sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
# Output
  col1  col2
0    x     1
1    a     2
2    b     3
3    f     6
4    c     4
```